# Serving Django CMS Admin Styles in Production with Apache

Tags: python, css, django, apache, wsgi

I made a simple site using Django CMS. Everything seems to work, except for the styles on the admin toolbar. They are not loading. What should I do to configure the app or server to serve them properly?

Here is the settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'some secret here'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'treebeard',
    'sekizai',
    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'mptt',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_video',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_column',
    'aldryn_bootstrap3',
    'parler',
    'aldryn_apphooks_config',
    'aldryn_categories',
    'aldryn_common',
    'aldryn_newsblog',
    'aldryn_people',
    'aldryn_reversion',
    'aldryn_translation_tools',
    'sortedm2m',
    'taggit',
    'reversion',
    'aldryn_boilerplates',
    'absolute',
    'aldryn_forms',
    'aldryn_forms.contrib.email_notifications',
    'captcha',
    'emailit',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'iboyko.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
                'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app_name.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]



MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

SITE_ID = 1

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('de', 'German'),
]

CMS_TEMPLATES = [
    ('base.html', 'Home page template'),
]

THUMBNAIL_HIGH_RESOLUTION = True

THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
    'filer.thumbnail_processors.scale_and_crop_with_subject_location',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters'
)
```

wsgi.conf:

```
# NOTE: mod_wsgi can not coexist in the same apache process as
# mod_wsgi_python3.  Only load if mod_wsgi_python3 is not
# already loaded.

<IfModule !wsgi_module>
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
</IfModule>

#WSGIScriptAlias /test_wsgi /var/www/vhosts/app_name/test_wsgi.py
#WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/app_name/app_name/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/app_name-blog-env:/var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/app_name-blog-env/lib/pyth$
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/app_name-blog-env

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This is name based virtual hosting. So place an appropriate server name
    #   here. Example: django.devsrv.local
    ServerName  app_name.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess iboyko python-home=/var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/app_name-blog-env
    WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}

    # Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/app_name/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/static/

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/static/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/media/
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/media/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
#Alias /static/admin/ /var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/app_name-blog-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contri$
    #Alias /static/admin/ /var/www/vhosts/app_name-blog/static/admin
    # PROCESS_NAME specifies a distinct name of this process
    #   see: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess
    # PATH/TO/PROJECT_ROOT is the full path to your project's root directory,
    #   containing your project files
    # PATH/TO/VIRTUALENV/ROOT: If you are using a virtualenv specify the full
    #   path to its directory.
    #   Generally you must specify the path to Python's site-packages.
    #WSGIDaemonProcess   {{ project_name }}  python-path={{ project_directory }}:{{ project_directory }}/../lib$
    #WSGIPythonPath /var/www/vhosts/app_name/:/var/www/vhosts/app_name/app_name-site/lib/python3.6/site-packages/

    # PROCESS_GROUP specifies a distinct name for the process group
    #   see: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIProcessGroup
    #WSGIProcessGroup    {{ project_name }}

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, making sure that `djangocms_admin_style` is installed, making sure that `STATIC_ROOT` variable is set in `settings.py` file and points to the absolute path of where one wants the static files to be served from are prerequisites to solving this.

`pip install djangocms_admin_style`

`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`

Lastly, running the following command fixes the issue:

`python manage.py collectstatic`

The wsgi.py file remains unchanged.